# Hide a label from an Embedded Form Type in a Collection type

Tags: forms, symfony, symfony-forms

I have a form collection type called `ContactType` which has a CollectionType field called `contact2Companies` with `entry_type` `AddCompanyFromContactType`. `AddCompanyFromContactType` has a field `company` which uses another form type `CompanyNameType`.

In the frontend, we see the label `Unternehmen` from `ContactType`. In the grey box, first line, is the label `Name des Unternehmens` which comes from `AddCompanyFromContactType` and under this the label `Name` which comes from `CompanyNameType`.

[image: frontend]

How can I hide/remove the label `Name`?

### Code Excerpts

#### ContactType

```
$builder
->add('contact2Companies', CollectionType::class, [
    'required' => false,
    'label' => 'contact.companies',
    'entry_type' => AddCompanyFromContactType::class,
    'allow_add' => true,
    'allow_delete' => true,
])
```

#### AddCompanyFromContactType

```
$builder
->add('company', CompanyNameType::class, [
    'required' => true,
    'label' => 'company.name',
    'attr' => [
        'autofocus' => true,
    ],
])
```

#### CompanyNameType

```
$builder
->add('name', TextType::class)
```

Answer (score 4):

Simply add this to the field `name` of `CompanyNameType`:

```
    $builder
        ->add('name', TextType::class, [
            'label' => false,
        ])
```

Answer (score 1):

CollectionType has 2 levels of labels. One for all inputs, and the other for each input in Collection.

[image]

```php
$builder->add('name', CollectionType::class, [
                'entry_type' => MoneyType::class,
                'label' => 'Top Name Label',
                'entry_options' => [
                    'label' => 'Name Label',
                ],
            ])
```

`label` on the first level is rendered in `<legend>` tag and it is one for all inputs.

`label` under `entry_options` is for each row.

According to your needs, you can set them `false`.